Проблема с pydub.AudioSegment.from_file (ffmpeg)
Когда пытаюсь преобразовать объект типа AudioData, то происходит ошибка. Уже перепробовал всё что можно, не могу решить проблему.
Вот код, ошибка происходит в переменной seg
async def once_done(sink: discord.sinks.MP3Sink, channel: discord.TextChannel, *args):
    words_list = []
    audio_segs: list[pydub.AudioSegment] = []
    longest = pydub.AudioSegment.empty()
    files: list[discord.File] = []

    for user_id, audio in sink.audio_data.items():
        try:
            payload: FileSource = {
                "buffer": audio.file.read(),
                "mimetype": "audio/mp3"  # Указываем тип аудиофайла
        }

            #audio.on_format("mp3")
            seg = pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(audio.file, format="mp3")

Сама ошибка:
    Exception in thread Thread-3 (recv_audio):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\olimp\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Work on Python\management-followups-bot\main.py", line 66, in once_done
    seg = pydub.AudioSegment.from_file(audio.file, format="mp3")
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\olimp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 773, in from_file
    raise CouldntDecodeError(
pydub.exceptions.CouldntDecodeError: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 3199971767

Output from ffmpeg/avlib:

ffmpeg version 2024-09-02-git-3f9ca51015-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 
--enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libquirc --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-libqrencode --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libvvenc --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      59. 35.100 / 59. 35.100
  libavcodec     61. 11.100 / 61. 11.100
  libavformat    61.  5.101 / 61.  5.101
  libavdevice    61.  2.100 / 61.  2.100
  libavfilter    10.  2.102 / 10.  2.102
  libswscale      8.  2.100 /  8.  2.100
  libswresample   5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
  libpostproc    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
[cache @ 000001b25c1c6e00] Inner protocol failed to seekback end : -40
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mp3 @ 000001b25c1c6840] Failed to find two consecutive MPEG audio frames.
[cache @ 000001b25c1c6e00] Statistics, cache hits:0 cache misses:0
[in#0 @ 000001b25c1ac740] Error opening input: Invalid data found when processing input
Error opening input file cache:pipe:0.
Error opening input files: Invalid data found when processing input


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\olimp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\olimp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\olimp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\voice_client.py", line 868, in recv_audio
    result = callback.result()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\olimp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 456, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\olimp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "c:\Users\olimp\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Work on Python\management-followups-bot\main.py", line 95, in once_done
    await channel.send(f"Ошибка при работе с Deepgram API: {str(e)}")
  File "C:\Users\olimp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1666, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\olimp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 374, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In content: Must be 2000 or fewer in length.

